# htaccess rewrite incorrectly requesting https resources

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any reason the following URL rewrite would result in resources being requested from https instead of http? The current site, which I'm attempting to rewrite to, is not requesting resources over https.

In `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olduglysubdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newawesomesubdomain.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

The correct html certainly loads, but the images, css, and JavaScript are all `https://newawesomesubdomain.domain.com/`. Can I force it to http via .htaccess, or is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Comment: Is there any .htaccess on `newawesomesubdomain.domain.com` domain also?

Comment: @anubhava there is absolutely nothing on `newawesomesubdomain.domain.com`